# Dictionary converted to array in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d={'a0': [['5021', '5031'], ['4994', '4991', '5042'],
          ['4992', '4995', '5021', '4994'], ['5037', '5038']],
   'a24': [['5009', '5014'], ['5009', '5014'], ['4993', '4998', '5030', '4991']]
}
```

I have the above dict in python.
I need to make list with the name of it being the names of keys in the dict.
The list with the name of the key should have the items as its corresponding values in dict.

The output should be:

```
a0=[['5021', '5031'], ['4994', '4991', '5042'],
              ['4992', '4995', '5021', '4994'], ['5037', '5038']]
a24=[['5009', '5014'], ['5009', '5014'], ['4993', '4998', '5030', '4991']]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example `a0 = d['a0']` ?

Comment: yes i did. how do i dynamically create a list with the name of the key in the dict?

Comment: You have the information in the dictionary. Why do you want to create lists from them?

Comment: the rest of the process begins from this level.

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can solve this problem without dynamically creating these variables. For example, you could make the rest of the process a function. And pass d['a0'] and d['a24'] as parameters.

Comment: could you expain.actually im beginner in python

Comment: my requirement is actually iterate over the values of a0, and a24 using nested for loops simultaneously

Comment: is it possible to simultaneusly iterate over the values of different keys of a dict?

Answer (score 0):

First, rethink if this is really necessary. Dynamically creating variables is confusing and does not occur often. It would be better to avoid this.

However, you can do it like this:

```
for name, val in d.items():
    exec("{}={}".format(name,val))
```

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback on why this is downvoted

Answer (score -1):

```
for key, item in d.items():
    print(str(key) + "=" + str(item))
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was how to dynamically create variables.

Comment: That's not what the question says and I'm not psychic. The output matched the questions desired output.

Comment: The OP mentions this in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026570/dictionary-converted-to-array-in-python/61026611#comment107964913_61026570): "*how do i dynamically create a list with the name of the key in the dict?*". The desired output is `a0` and `a24` are the *variable* names of the lists extracted from the dict, not simply printing key=value pairs to the console. I admit though that the question really wasn't that clear enough.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I am not pshycic. I answered the question as it was when I answered and cannot open a time portal and view extra information the OP adds after the fact. When I answered the desired output was the only solid description of what was needed.